# Free and simple video editor for Windows 10

Tags: mixing, clipping

I need a free and **simple to use tool** that is able to cut vidoes, fade to another videos (or instant change without any fade) and overlap audio (music or out of screen voices). Basically the basic features that everyone expect from a video editor and that almost all programs do not have.

Finding such a program for Windows 10 is a real challenge. In the meanwhile I become a expert in HandBrake transcoder, but still searching for a video editor.

Comment: Non of the video editors in that answer were useful, some crashed, some Others were so complex that I just become bored after halfhour/ 1 hour of.
"simple too use"

Comment: Upvoting as it seems some of the answers in the suggested duplicate do not work nowadays or on Windows 10.  The question could be re-worded to focus on Windows 10 and simplicity of use with a drag and drop style interface.

Comment: And someone should remove the "duplicate" tag :_D

Comment: While some of the answers in the dupe may not work for you, this question really is a duplicate.

Comment: None of the answers work in the dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are going to be uploading to [YouTube](https://youtube.com/) anyway you can use the [YouTube Video Editor](https://youtube.com/editor) that they include for free in Creator Studio.  It includes the ability to cut and spice videos as well as add music or other audio channels.  YouTube also includes a selection of free (as in beer and speech to the degree that you can use it on YouTube) music that you can easily add to the background.

There are several video tutorials available on YouTube if you search for [YouTube Video Editor Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=youtube%20editor%20tutorial), such as this [tutorial for 2017](https://youtu.be/6QnaRRuezqw).

Outside of that the free ones I know of are mostly Linux based so will be of no use for a Windows 10 user.

---

For older versions of Windows and those of us living in the past there was Windows Movie Maker included as part of Windows Essentials ([see a past answer for details](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/15542/10839)).  If you are using Windows 10 or living in a time post January 2017 then Movie Maker is no longer available.